# How to use Python requests library to send raw HTTP request message?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a process on a local machine listening on a port which I can send a raw HTTP request message to in the form of

```
GET /hello HTTP/1.1
...
```

and it will respond correctly. It works when I do

```
cat request | nc localhost 1111 > response
```

where 'request' file contains the same HTTP request message. How can I do that with requests library? It doesn't work if I write

```
requests.get("http://localhost:1111/hello", headers=...)
```

Alternatively, is it possible to use requests library's response parsing engine to parse a raw HTTP response message, since I can get that through a socket connection? I'd like to get to response's message body which is in a Json format.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? And yes, it is possible to use the built in features to parse a json response.

Comment: I'm getting 'Not Found\n' as a response.

Comment: requests is mostly an higher level api built on top of urllib which is itself built on even lower level components, so obviously what you are looking for is not in requests. Googling for 'python http parser' should get you started

Comment: wrt/ json there's a json parser in the stdlib so once you have your response parsed it's just a matter of passing the response body to json.loads()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if something funky is going on with your local host setup. Are you just using that to test or what? But here is how that would normally go

```
import requests
url=r'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1' #just a url with test json data

r=requests.get(url) #note that headers aren't 100% needed 

j=r.json() #j is now a python dict object

print(j)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how localhost is configured, but as far as I'm aware, it's a production server and it works as it should, and they're not going to change it for me. As I pointed out I can get a valid response with a `nc localhost 1111` command, or using a socket in Python, but not with a `requests.get`. But then I'm stuck with a raw HTTP response message that I don't know how to parse easily to get straight to a message body.